# ARKit and SpriteKit: how to remove the SKScene?

Tags: ios, memory-management, sprite-kit, skscene, arkit

My AR feature is not a core feature in my app, users may optionally navigate to a viewController with an `ARSKView` where I configure and set an `SKScene` in the `ARsession`.

When the user navigates back from that viewController and it is pop from the navigationController where it was pushed, I noticed that the func `update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval)` in my `SKScene` subclass was kept being called... so I added this to the viewController:

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

    sceneView.session.pause()
    sceneView.scene?.isPaused = true
}
```

However, for me that is not a solution because when I navigate back from the view controller that holds the `ARSKView` and it is deinitialized, I see that the `SKScene` is kept in memory and a new one is created every time I navigate again to the AR related view controller. So, if I navigate there N times, I see I have N `SKScenes` in memory.

How could I appropiately handle this and remove the scene when navigating back? The scene property of the `ARsession` is read only.

**EDIT:** In the view controller I have:

```
fileprivate let sceneView = ARSKView()

private func setup() {
    if ARWorldTrackingConfiguration.isSupported {
        let myScene = MyScene(size: sceneView.bounds.size)
        myScene.sceneDelegate = self
        myScene.scaleMode = .resizeFill

        sceneView.delegate = self
        sceneView.presentScene(myScene)
    }
}
```

I don't have any property to the `SKScene`.

Comment: You have bigger problems with your code,  you need to retain a pointer to your SKScene or ARView after it is removed, and make sure that you are reusing this pointer in the spot where you are creating the SKScene instance

Comment: If your view is being removed from memory, your scene should also be removed from memory.  If it is staying, then you have what is called a retain cycle,  where your scene is being retained by a block, and a block is retaining a scene, so nothing is getting deinit

Comment: @Knight0fDragon I dont have declared any property to the `SKScene` in the view controller, but one to the `ARSKView`. Then in the view controller I create the scene and associate it to the `sceneView` as I show now in my question.

Comment: Yes, that is a problem if you need to save the SKScene,  If you do not need to save, then you need to find out what is retaining the scene.  I discussed both scenarios in my last 2 comments.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon also the `ARSKView` is retained, and a new one is created everytime the view controller is.

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do here,  your problems seem to stem beyond the scope of your question.  Perhaps you need to go back and determine what your problem really is and come back with a question that has better clarity to your problem.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon I'm just trying to remove the `ARSKView` and the `SKScene` from memory once the view controller is deinitialized, since I dont need them anymore. But they are retained, and when I create the view controller again then new `ARSKView` and `SKScene` are created while the former are kept in memory. I tried to make the property to the `ARSceneView` weak but it does not seem to work.

Comment: Then you have a retain cycle that you need to find, nobody here can help you find that.

Comment: @AppsDev There was a memory leak in ARSKView. Apple has resolved this in ios 12.

Answer (score 0):

There was a memory leak in ARSKView. Apple has resolved this in ios 12.